# Issue receiving an access token

Tags: javascript, axios, jira-rest-api

Having some issues getting an access token from Jira. It works perfectly fine through postman, however I'm struggling to get it work using axios. There's been several iterations of the code below, nearly all of which are throwing back the same error.

Receiving the following error:
Error: Request failed with status code 403

edit:
auth docs here
https://developer.atlassian.com/cloud/jira/platform/oauth-2-authorization-code-grants-3lo-for-apps/

```
 const headers = { "Content-Type": "application/json" };

 axios
   .post("https://auth.atlassian.com/oauth/token",
     {
       grant_type: "authorization_code",
       client_id: `${process.env.JIRA_CLIENT_ID}`,
       client_secret: `${process.env.JIRA_CLIENT_SECRET}`,
       code: auth_code,
       redirect_uri: "https://localhost:3000"
     },
     { headers: headers }
   )
```

Comment: Please check if authorization or key or any value needs to be passed in header ?

Comment: @VinodkumarG The information is all correct, as noted it works perfectly fine with postman, so I'm suspecting that it's something related to formatting.

Comment: in Postman itself, you can take the equalvalent code, please check that also, see if cookies or anything get passed, bascially it is forbidden error 403. so something stops in client side only.

Comment: May the redirect_uri is not listed under the trusted urls of the jira secrets?

Comment: Does you got an error with client_id and secret as constant value too? test it with not using with environment variables and check it is not empty.

Comment: @TasosBu The same redirect_uri works in postman (the uri given here was just an example), would that still be possible?

Comment: @JoonaYoon Yea have tested that too

Comment: Please check what the value of `auth_code` for code property is too. it was received from the initial authorize call correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, managed to figure it out, the issue was that the auth_code was being stringified prior to passing it to the body